# Silverlight: Access XAML control from code

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, compiler-errors

I'm having a problem accessing a Panel control defined on the XAML of a page, the XAML is defined this way:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="PhoneBook.SilverlightMainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="400" Height="300" d:DesignWidth="993" d:DesignHeight="887">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" />
</UserControl>
```

The class is defined like this:

```
public partial class SilverlightMainPage : UserControl
{
    public SilverlightMainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        
}
```

And I'm trying to instantiate it this way:

```
var silverlightMainPage = new PhoneBook.SilverlightMainPage();
SomeMethod((silverlightMainPage.LayoutRoot);
```

What I find strange is that when I put the dot after the object instance, it actually list LayoutRoot as one of the members, but when I try to compile the application it says that there's no member with that name.

Any ideas of what can be hapenning?

Thanks

EDIT: I also tried creating a property on the SilverlightMainPage class that returned the LayoutRoot element, but it also says that the class doesn't contain a definition for Layout root.

Comment: Try right-clicking on the InitializeComponent() method and then selecting "Go to Definition".  Do you see LayoutRoot there?

Comment: Where is that panel you cannot access?  Where do you instanciate the Main page?  From the App.xaml?  Can you provide the code of SomeMethod()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the problem.

I was generating the project automatically with a tool built by someone else in the company.

I did some extra tests and added a new UserControl to the project and tried to access the LayoutRoot from a property in the code behind, and it worked.

Then copied the exact same code to the file with the problem (just changing the class name) and it didn't compile.

Then I checked the project file, and found a section like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="SilverlightMainPage.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>SilverlightMainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Which for some reason was causing the compilation to fail.
I removed that section and now everything works fine.

Thanks for your answers though.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that you're trying to access SilverlightMainPage.LayoutRoot from a different assembly?  In the MainPage.g.i.cs file, LayoutRoot (and all other controls defined in XAML) are marked "internal", i.e.:

```
    internal System.Windows.Controls.Grid LayoutRoot;
```

You might want to try creating a public rather than an internal property that does a FindName("LayoutRoot") and returns the appropriate control.